# Using App Script to open a dialog in Spreadsheet that is served in an IFRAME generates "docs.google.com refused to connect."

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a web application that has Google Sheets embedded using an IFRAME. The embedding works great but if I try to create an AppScript code that opens a dialog window using HtmlService I get a gray box with:

docs.google.com refused to connect.

I've tried setting the IFRAME in emulated and native mode. Also tried setting .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL) on the HtmlService and it does not work.

Sample code:

```js
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const html = HtmlService
   .createHtmlOutput('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hey</body></html>')
   .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Title');
```

Comment: Any logs on the console?

Comment: Share your code snippet.

Comment: Try using JQuery UI Dialog

Comment: Sample code:    

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hey</body></html>').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
  
 ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Title');

Comment: Log: Refused to display 'https://docs.google.com/..' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: If I use JQuery can I still talk to Google Apps Script to get and send data? Any examples of this?

Comment: I would not be able to add JQuery UI Dialog because I cannot run any HTML.

Comment: Hello Néstor Boscán, did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same problem on my website. Thank you, Garry